# Web server best practices

Tags: android, sqlite, rest, web

I need a suggestion on a design decision.
I am creating a ecommmerce app and have a lot of items (>10000) to show in my app. Now here are the 2 options I have
1) Get all the items information from the server and save in local db and synchronize the information every time (let say 15 min)
2) Get the information every time from the web server (through rest api).

There are pros and cons of both the methods. Using local db I can get fast results and less server bandwidth but will have to handle synchronization
With second approach, I will have a lot of server request to and free and load on server.

I would also like to know how does other apps like amazon and flipkart handle this. Do they save in local db or request server every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should be looking for is a mixed design between local and remote.

In terms of data types there are two major types:

- blobs 'binary large objects' for example: images, videos ...
- and small data (usually json/xml representation of the items).

Amazon and other web apps provide fresh data every time the app loads, and at the same time keeps a local copy of the data incase the app went offline, or sometimes even use that data in the next load while waiting for the backend.

On the other end those app maintain a cache level for large data so that they don't have to load it more than once.

But the key for this to work is to have a very fast backend that contains many features to improve its speed including:

- cloud front end that allows users to communicate with the closest server around them.
- memcached or any other caching technology that will keep the info about the items in the RAM in the servers and not having to query the database to get them.

what usually happens is that the backend ensures that its data always loaded in the ram/cache by ether querying the database every specific time or by pushing to cache every time an insert/delete/update happened to the database.

[Here is how Twitter is doing it](http://highscalability.com/blog/2013/7/8/the-architecture-twitter-uses-to-deal-with-150m-active-users.html)

**One last note** Your app shouldn't take longer to interact with more than a web page, its not acceptable for native apps to take longer than web apps to allow the user to interact with them.

Answer (score 1):

Only load what you want to show, but cache intelligently.

For example; an image for a product isn't going to change very often, but the amount of items available for a very popular item can change every second. Decide on a case by case basis what piece of information to refresh and when.

You **definitely** don't want to pull down everything from your server every time someone launches the app. That does not result in lower bandwidth. It will melt your server, eat up their data plan, and fill their phone storage with products that they will never see.